# How to assign a variable to req.parmas in node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, parameter-passing

I want to assign a variable for the value `id` in `req.params.id` as shown below.
This is what I've tried, but is not working:

```html
router.get("/users/:id", function(req,res){
     Campground.findById(req.params.id, function(err,foundingdUser){
     var user = foundingdUser.author.id; // i want to use this value for the next findById
      if(err) {
        req.flash("error", "Something went wrong.");
        return res.redirect("/");
      }else{
          User.findById(req.params.user,function(err,foundUser){  // i want to use the value of user here but it is not working
              if(err){
                  req.flash("error","Something went wrong.");
                  return res.redirect("/");
              }else{
                //console.log(foundUser);
                res.render("profile",{use: foundUser})  
              }
          })
      }
    })    
})
```

Comment: see express documentation below https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You assigned the id to the variable user so you should:

```
User.findById(user,function(err,foundUser){ ...
```

Or you can `req.params.user = foundingdUser.author.id;` and keep the rest as it was if you want it like this for some reason